# How to authenticate Microsoft Auth on Xamarin.ios native app in order to get access to MS account?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin.ios native app and I have to authenticate/login with microsoft account to access Microsoft Graph Api or other outlook api. I have done the all settings in Azure active directory, So I have already try to implement this by using xamarin.auth but this is not working due to grant_type parameter is not being supplied and throw an error as **invalid_grant** and **invalid_request**.
is any other way to authenticate with microsoft account? 
can you help me to implement **Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET (MSAL)** in xamarin.ios native app. I got some sample xamarin.forms but we need it in xamarin.ios. I am not familiar with xamarin.forms code.

Comment: Hi , do you have a check with this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/mobile-apps .

Comment: Yes I have checked it but not getting solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET (MSAL.NET) on Xamarin iOS, you should:

- Override and implement the OpenUrl function in AppDelegate.
- Enable keychain groups.
- Enable token cache sharing.
- Enable keychain access.
- Understand known issues with iOS 12 and authentication.

Having a look at this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-ios-considerations

Comment: I have read this document and implemented Openurl() method in appdeligate.cs. I have also done it for google. After that I have enabled Keychain access and group according to doc. MSAL added to my project earlier so just write this code as  `var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
              .Create("MyClientID")
              .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.MyApp.GetContactDemo")
              .Build();`
But not getting the microsoft authentication window for login.

Comment: @SumitMishra Okey , your tested version of iOS whether is 13 above ? Do you have a check with known issue with iOS 12 .

Comment: Yes, My app is running on iOS 12 and I understand the issue but how to solve this xamarin.ios because I am not using ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: @SumitMishra About other solutions , now I have no idea . If found good solution will update here later :)